# Saber cual es el ultimo archivo subido en php

Tags: php

Tengo un script php en el que recorro una carpeta y cojo el ultimo archivo (ordenado alfabeticamente) lo que quiero hacer y no consigo es que coja el ultimo archivo pero ordenado por fecha. suben los archivos por ftp y yo tengo que leer la carpeta y registrar el ultimo subido, pero no se como hacer que coja el ultimo subido.

```
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    require('conexion.php');
    set_time_limit(30000);
    //Cojo el nombre de la carpeta alias numero de serie de la herramienta
    $folder = $_GET["name"];
    //Escaneo todos los archivos de la carpeta
    $dircontents = scandir('../uploads/'.$folder.'/', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
    //recorro los archivos
    foreach ($dircontents as $file) {
        //cojo la extension del archivo
        $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //si es imagen apunto la url
        if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'mp3' || $extension == 'pdf' || $extension == 'doc' || $extension == 'docx' || $extension == 'mp4') {
            $fileName ='../uploads/'.$folder.'/'.$file ;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Has probado a aplicar un `usort` después del scandir? Podrías definir tu función para que te lo ordene según el campo creación...

Comment: La verdad es que nunca he usado el usort, podrías darme algún detalle mas?

Comment: @Superchicken creo que es mas simple en ver la documentacion [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php)